# Remote Desktop Services - Shut down application immediately instead of disconnecting it?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2019, remoteapp

I have some *RemoteApps* published via *Remote Desktop Services* and in one of these apps the user can open PDF files which basically launches *Acrobat Reader* and displaying the PDF.

The problem I'm facing is that when the user close the *Acrobat Reader* application (by clicking the [X] icon on the upper right corner of Acrobat Reader) the process isn't killed (I've managed to get it to shut down after 1 minute using GPO's) **and this becomes a problem if the user opens the same PDF-file again**, because the published *RemoteApp* application will create a **pop-up informing the user that this file is already opened** (but it's no longer visible for the user).

**So my question is if it's possible to force Remote Desktop Services to actually & immediately shut down an application when it's closed instead of disconnecting it?**

I've already played around with the "Session Time Limits" GPO's but the closest I can get is that the application is "disconnected" for 1 minute before it's logged off (and thus the process is killed) but I want it to be killed pretty much directly after the user press the [X].

Comment: It seems an expensive solution to use RDP sessions, just to view a PDF. The minimum time for logoff seems to be 1 minute as you found out.   This combined should make you look for an alterative solution. Maybe you can copy the PDF to a unique (random) filename, so it does not get in the way when re-opening?  This should work in combination of the already implemented logoff

Comment: I purpose of the solution is not to view a PDF but rather access an application where 0,1% of the capabilities is to check the PDF. The application launches the PDF viewer so I have no possibility to change how it does that without breaking some copyright laws and decompile the code and change it. Not a route I want to go down.

Comment: Another suggestion might be to check for old sessions in the logon script.

Comment: Thanks that might be a good idea. Check running disconnected sessions and kill them in the login script.